# Inserting records into SQL Server, how to update on conflict?

Tags: sql-server, merge, insert, upsert

I have a statement that looks like this:

```
Insert into table (value1, value2, value3)
Values (%s, %s, %s)
```

Could I do something where it will attempt to insert, but on conflict update value2 and value3 where value1 = value1 (i.e., value1 equals the duplicate primary key that is trying to be inserted against)?

Comment: Use the `MERGE` statement instead of `INSERT` ??

Comment: What would that look like? I've never used merge.

Comment: Read [the official MSDN documentation for `MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql), and have a look at [The MERGE Statement in SQL Server 2008](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/) on Simple-Talk for more background info

Answer (score 0):

For one insert (assuming value1 is a key)

```
  UPDATE TOP (1) table
     SET value2 = %s, value3 = %s
   WHERE value1 = %s;
 
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN      
      INSERT table (value1, value2, value3)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
  END
```

For multiple inserts

1. define a procedure for a table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE table_upsert  (@value1 bigint, @value2 nvarchar(255), @value3 nvarchar(255))
AS 
BEGIN TRAN
 
  UPDATE TOP (1) table WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
     SET value2 = @value2, value3 = @value3
   WHERE value1 = @value1;
 
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN      
      INSERT table (value1, value2, value3)
      VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3);
  END 
COMMIT
```

2. call the procedure with parameters

```
EXEC table_upsert %s, %s, %s
```

Answer (score -3):

```
INSERT INTO table (value1, value2, value3) VALUES(%s, %s, %s) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  value2=%s, value3=%s
```

Comment: This is tagged with sql server and this is a mysql construct.

Comment: @Jasonca1 Have you tried this ? I do not think this will work in sql-server.

Comment: in which sql server version "ON DUPLICATE KEY" has been implemented?